# improve compile time with Large Asset Catalog?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, assets, asset-catalog

I have an app that is a compilation of several apps. My asset catalog has 1000+ images.

Does anyone know how to speed up compile times?

I have my build settings set to incremental and have the asset compression set to lowest size. My asset catalog takes 10min to compile on an initial build. Is there a way to precompile sections etc?

Comment: Break it into separate catalogs in separate frameworks?

Comment: Yes that's one option. I was hoping to avoid that but perhaps that's the only answer.

Comment: I don't guarantee it would make a difference but it's worth a try. Costs nothing to try it!

Comment: I personally put 5 big assets in a separate Swift Package. 

It was the first time that I create a package with resources in it. It tooks me 2 hours.

I think that build time is better in some cases, but it looks like Xcode still rebuild this package too often.

Xcode really sucks for build time since Swift and SwiftUI has been introduced...